# Add & remove class when I click in body by JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using filter everything plugin for woocommerse. I did some customize for filter but still some issues with JS. when I click to filter it's open the list but when I click out of box it's not close

the plugin use the following script

```js
$(document).on('click', '.wpc-filter-title button', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let $filterSection = $(this).parents('.wpc-filters-section');
        let filterId       = $filterSection.data( 'fid' );

        if ( $filterSection.hasClass( 'wpc-opened' ) ) {
            $filterSection.removeClass( 'wpc-opened' )
                .addClass( 'wpc-closed' );
            setStatusCookie( -filterId, wpcStatusCookieName );
        } else if ( $filterSection.hasClass( 'wpc-closed' ) ) {
            $filterSection.removeClass( 'wpc-closed' )
                .addClass( 'wpc-opened' );
            setStatusCookie( filterId, wpcStatusCookieName );
        } else {
           if( $filterSection.hasClass( 'wpc-filter-has-selected' ) || $filterSection.hasClass( 'wpc-filter-collapsible-reverse' ) ) {
                $filterSection.removeClass( 'wpc-opened' )
                    .addClass( 'wpc-closed' );
               setStatusCookie( -filterId, wpcStatusCookieName );
           } else {
               $filterSection.removeClass( 'wpc-closed' )
                   .addClass( 'wpc-opened' );
               setStatusCookie( filterId, wpcStatusCookieName );
           }
        }
    });
```

I added the following in the function.php (header function)

```js
<script>
    jQuery(document).on('click', 'body', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.wpc-filters-section'))hasClass('wp-opened')
      $('.wpc-filters-section').removeClass('wpc-opened').addClass('wpc-closed');
  });
</script>
```

could you please help me to fix it? my idea I want the list closed after click any where

Comment: Something is wrong here `if (!$(e.target).is('.wpc-filters-section'))hasClass('wp-opened')`

Comment: but I should select this dev has this class to do that

Comment: 1. Look at what's missing between `)` and `hasClass`. 2. `is()` returns a boolean, so you can't call `hasClass()` on that

Comment: thank you for your response, I changed the code to the following but it's working but it's not cover all the button do you have any suggest to fix it ?   jQuery(document).on('click', 'body', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.wpc-filter-title button'))
      $('.wpc-filters-section').removeClass('wpc-opened')
  .addClass('wpc-closed');
  });

Answer (score 0):

The code below allows you to add class "wpc-opened" and remove class "wpc-closed" when the the filter is closed. And add class "wpc-closed" and remove class "wpc-opened" when the filter is opened or when you click out of the button.

```js
$(window).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if ($(e.target).is('.wpc-filter-title button')) {
        let $filterSection = $(e.target).parents('.wpc-filters-section');
        let filterId = $filterSection.data( 'fid' );
        
        if ( $filterSection.hasClass( 'wpc-opened' ) ) {
            $filterSection.removeClass( 'wpc-opened' ).addClass( 'wpc-closed' );
            //setStatusCookie( -filterId, wpcStatusCookieName );
        } else if ( $filterSection.hasClass( 'wpc-closed' ) ) {
            $(".wpc-filters-section").removeClass( 'wpc-opened' ).addClass( 'wpc-closed' );
            $filterSection.removeClass( 'wpc-closed' ).addClass( 'wpc-opened' );
            //setStatusCookie( filterId, wpcStatusCookieName );
        }
    }
    else if (!$(e.target).is('.filter-block')) {
        $(".wpc-filters-section").removeClass( 'wpc-opened' ).addClass( 'wpc-closed' );
    }
  
});
```

```css
.wpc-closed .filter-block {
    display: none;
}

.flex-block {
    display: flex;
}

.flex-block .wpc-filters-section {
    width: 120px;
}

.flex-block .filter-block{
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="flex-block">
    <div class="wpc-filters-section wpc-closed">
        <div class="wpc-filter-title">
            <button id="showFilter">Test</button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="filter-block">
            The content of block for Test
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="wpc-filters-section wpc-closed">
        <div class="wpc-filter-title">
            <button id="showFilter">Test 2</button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="filter-block">
            The content of block for Test 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your response ... I tried it it's not working for me I edited the code to the following it's working but the issue is not covered all the button 
<script>
    jQuery(document).on('click', 'body', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.wpc-filter-title button'))
      $('.wpc-filters-section').removeClass('wpc-opened').addClass('wpc-closed');
  });
</script>
do you have any suggest ?

Comment: Can you give me your HTML code (only the part that contain the filter) and your js code. Can you tell me which buttons (or cases) doesn't work actually ?

Comment: this is link direct to see the filter 
https://allbrandsfactoryoutlet.com/new/product-category/2-women/

Comment: I think that your code JS doesn't read in your page.
Can you check if your code was read by your page, by putting a console message in your function and your condition ?

Comment: I removed it because there are problem .. my idea I want close the button after click other button or outside the button ..when you check the website now and click the button it will still open till you click on it again

Comment: I have adapt the code of the solution.
Can you check it with running the code snippet ? 
It work correctly.

Comment: perfect this is what I want it ... I tried the code in my website after I changed filter-block css to wpc-filter-content it's the css in my website .. no issues but the button is not open Note: after I added the code there are clickable issue in all links it's nit working